# Sticky Views while react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-android

Im trying to build a mobile app where we have a constant header bar throughout the app. I have the body where I have buttons.. Each button navigates to a `screen`. I need the `header bar` in every screen but I dont wish to repeat the code in all screens. I dont intend to use TabNavigator either. Is there any alternative??

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

in image1 and image 2 the bar with the search,cart and offerzone tag remains same. The rest changes..I need this behaviour without repeating the header code in both screens.

Comment: ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the code of `headerBar` into a independent component, and use `redux store` to manage this component's props.

After you do this, you just need to import the component in each screen, the component will get its props from redux store automatically. Each screen can contact `headerBar` with `redux actions`

Comment: No I don't want to import the component in each screen. I would prefer something like frames in HTML where 2 frames are independent of each other.